# Working with multiple forms using c# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm currently developing a Windows Form Application that uses two forms. I have no problems linking between the two forms. My issue is accessing a variable in Form2 that was created in Form1. How do you make a variable accessible to multiple forms in the same project?. I honestly tried to look for an answer, but could not find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code for Form1:

```
  namespace HourlyAlarm1
  {
    public partial class AlarmToneSetter : Form
     {
       public bool halfHourSelected;

       public AlarmToneSetter()
       { 
          InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          if(halfHourRadio.Checked)
          {
            halfHourSelected = true;
          }
          else
          {
            halfHourSelected = false;
          }

          Form1 f1 = new Form1();
          f1.ShowDialog();
      }

      public bool getHalfHourSelect()
      {
         return halfHourSelected;
      }
   }
 }
```

Here is the code for Form2:

```
    namespace HourlyAlarm1
    {
      public partial class Form1 : Form
      {
        int min;
        System.Media.SoundPlayer sp;

        public Form1()
       {
          InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void playSound()
       {
         sp = new      System.Media.SoundPlayer(HourlyAlarm1.Properties.Resources.chipfork);
         sp.Load();
         sp.Play();
       }

       private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          TimeLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
          min = DateTime.Now.Minute;

          if(HourlyAlarm1.AlarmToneSetter.g)
          if(min == 0)
          {
            playSound();
          }

      }
  }
```

}

Comment: Mark it public? Pass a reference in? Could you be a bit more specific as to what you tried and what error you are receiving?

Comment: Which variable of which form you want to access in which other form?

Comment: The solution this depends on how you want to access the variable of other form. You wan to access updated value of the variable no matter how many instances of the form is created? Or you want access the value of a variable which represents a state of the form? It would not be a simple solution if your requirement is 2nd among the two I mentioned above.

Comment: Which variable you want to make global? How many forms going to use this variable?

Answer (score -1):

If you want a variable which is accessible to any form within the project, mark it as static. That way you don't need a specific instance of the class that it's in to be able to access it.

Comment: That is just god awful architecture advice

Comment: Perhaps you could suggest an alternate approach that you would consider "good architecture advice" rather than just criticising all the suggestions? The OP wants a variable which is globally accessible to all Forms in the project. Without going into multi-threading territory, can you at least comment in greater depth about the flaw you see in the architecture?

Comment: Well you can see my post to start, although even that is insuffient in my mind if you really want to talk Windows Forms architecture. For one you can't put a static variable on an interface, which means DI basically goes out the window. The Model-View-Presenter pattern described here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ankithakur/mvp-design-pattern-for-window-forms/ is probably the most successful I've seen in Win Forms apps.

Comment: You can debate proper design until the cows come home, but a static variable seemed like the simplest route to the OP's answer, given that it doesn't strike me as something being used for production code. Your answer doesn't do much more than wrap the variable in a class which must now be passed via construction to each Form which wants to use it. What if Form2 created a Form3 which didn't use the variable, but Form3 created a Form4 which did? Now you're stuck passing the class to Form3 purely for transition. Static variables aren't great design, but they are much more maintainable long-term.

Comment: If your using constructor injection without a container dependency your passing dependencies like that all the time, which is the recommended practice per the Microsoft Patterns and Practices Team. Having random static variables are the opposite of maintainable long term as as projects go through their life cycle inevitably they grow in number and its not even immediately clear which ones are in use or for what.

Comment: Your first sentence implies that the OP has an understand of DI, which, judging by the scope of the question, they do not. The second sentence implies that this is a question intended for use in production code. Chances are, the question was asked by either a hobbyist or someone studying C#/WinForms, in which case wouldn't it be better to have the shortest, easiest to understand route to the answer? I'm not suggesting your answer is wrong, just that your criticism of the other answers on here is more aggressive than it should be.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the forms Tag property if you want to pass just one variable.

`Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.Tag="some value";
f1.ShowDialog();`

and then in form 2 access it via it's own Tag property. Since it is stored as an object you will have to convert it to whatever datatype your application requires.

Example for getting the value in the new form:

`string value = this.Tag.ToString();`

Comment: To me tag's are just as bad as public Tuple's because the caller has absolutely no idea what the value means

Answer (score -1):

As the question currently stands, it looks like you're trying to edit the `halfHourSelected` field in your `AlarmToneSetter` class from the `Form1` class. To do that, there are several options:

1. Since this field is already public you can simply edit it like this (form Form1):

   ```
   HourlyAlarm1.AlarmToneSetter.halfHourSelected = true;
   ```

   or, if you plan on using it several times, add

   ```
   using HourlyAlarm1;

   /** 
    * declare the namespace, the class, etc.
    */

   AlarmToneSetter.halfHourSelected = true
   ```
2. (Edit: As mentioned by Jason, this can be rewritten to be a property and comply with the style guide) However, since you already wrote a Java-style getter for this field, you should rewrite it in C# style; changing the declaration to

   ```
   public bool HalfHourSelected{get;set;};
   ```

   which will add the getter and setter for the property automatically.
3. Now, if you want to make this field persistent (that is, the configuration value should be saved across multiple executions of the program) then you should consider adding it to the settings of your project, and reference it like this

   ```
   HourlyAlarm1.Properties.Settings.Default.halfHourSelected = true;
   HourlyAlarm1.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
   ```

   or, as always, if you're gonna access them several times,

   ```
   using HourlyAlarm1.Properties;

   /** 
    * declare the namespace, the class, etc.
    */

   Settings.Default.halfHourSelected = true;
   Settings.Default.Save();
   ```

Yes, this is my first time answering a question in SO. If you have any recommendations, let me know in the comments! I'll appreciate the feedback.

Comment: You missed his problem of expecting that variable/property to change in Form1 when its changed in Form2. Which it won't since Boolean is a value type. Also there is no need for the private field as auto properties have been in C# for some time now (2.0?)

Comment: @Jason See, I don't understand what you say it's wrong with my answer. He's asking, literally, "How do you make a variable accessible to multiple forms in the same project?" and I showed him how to access a public field, how to encapsulate it and access it using a method, and provided a different approach altogether. As for the unnecessary `private` keyword, I corrected it

Comment: Yeah but if you look at the code he's clearly expecting the value to change and is his real questions, as inspite the limitations of it being a field and not a property the code as written would work the same as what you posted. The guy is new stackoverflow and probably to development in general, you really need to read between the lines to really get at what they're going for sometimes

Comment: Also it's not the private key word, you don't need the field! public bool HalfHourSelected{get;set;}. Also properties, unlike fields, start with an upper case and fields starting with _ are against Microsoft's style guidelines

Comment: @Jason Silly me, yes, got that changed already. Old habits. As for the rest, I believe this makes it a property itself of the form, making sure any assignations will be shallow-copied. Although I might be wrong, some quick testing in Visual Studio seems to agree.

Comment: From my read of the code he is expecting the value to change in Form1 when he changes it in Form2, which won't happen regardless of whether the Boolean is a field or property. Indeed value types, like bool, are copied on assignment.

Answer (score -1):

1. Pass them as parameter of constructor. This way is used to set once time at creating an instance of class

   public Form1(int i, string s, object o){}
2. Create public get/set. This way is used to set multiple times, but their value will be different among instances of class.

   public int Price { get; set;}

   Form1 frm1 = new Form1();

   frm1.Price = 123;
3. Create public static field. This way is used to set multiple times, and it is same among instance of class.

   public static int Price = 0;

   Form1.Price = 123;

Comment: First of all you can't have static fields or properties named the same as instance fields or properties. Second of all I see no binding between these two properties. But lastly, as I have discussed extensively in this question using a static variable is god awful architecture.

Answer (score -2):

First of all public fields are discouraged in .NET: you should use properties.

Your problem is that bool is a value type and you can't "bind" it between forms, you need a reference type.

```
public class ReferenceBoolean
{
      public bool Value{get;set;}
}
public class Form1
{
   protected ReferenceBoolean HalfHourSelectedReference{get;set;}
   public bool HalfHourSelected
   {
      get{return this.HalfHourSelectedReference.Value;}
      set{this.HalfHourSelectedReference.Value = value;}
   }
   public Form1()
   {
       this.HalfHourSelectedReference = new ReferenceBoolean();
   }
}
public class Form2
{
    protected ReferenceBoolean HalfHourSelectedReference{get;set;}
   public bool HalfHourSelected
   {
      get{return this.HalfHourSelectedReference.Value;}
      set{this.HalfHourSelectedReference.Value = value;}
   }

    public Form2(ReferenceBoolean halfHourSelected)
    {
        this.HalfHourSelectedReference = value;
    }
}
```

Now this might look all fine and dandy but there is one thing I did not do, because I'm not sure if you need it, if you update this value and have it bound to the UI in your form the update will not be reflected in the form. To do that you must implement something like the IPropertyNotificationChange pattern, which works much better in WPF.